# Grad school admissions with multiple colleges?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Does anyone know anything about grad school admissions with multiple undergrad institutions?

I dropped out about 5 years ago with an abysmal (~1.7 GPA) as a math major halfway through sophomore year (so 1.5 years done) but am now looking into going back in preparation for grad school to fulfill that dream of being a Math PhD.

I've taken time off and fixed my mental health and am doing pretty well (gotten a good job, saved up a lot, gotten engaged etc.) and ready to give this another shot!

I was wondering, if I go back to school to what extent would they care about my old grades after I have the bachelor's from a new college (also in Math)? What if I retake old failed courses?

Am 24 now and in the US by the way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that, when you apply to graduate programs, you'll be asked about *all* your undergrad work; if so, then you should truthfully include your previous bad experience. Fortunately, I don't think it will have much effect on your chances of admission. When we admit grad students, we care about their abilities and attitudes at that point and in the future, not 5 (or 7 by the time you're applying) years in the past.